# OpenGL ES perspective projection

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es, android-animation

I'm having a hard time understanding how `glFrustum` & `gluPerspective` work. I understand the concept of perspective projection but the functions aren't behaving how I expect them to.
For example, if I set the frustum this way

```
glFrustumf(0, 10, 0, 10, 1, 100)
```

and have a rectangle at points

```
 0,   0,  1,
 0,  10,  1,
10,  10,  1,
10,   0,  1
```

then the rectangle is drawn with it's left half outside the screen. And if the left half is outside the screen, I'd expect the vertical half to be outside too. But that doesn't happen either.

In whatever examples I've seen, the coordinates for the projection matrix are taken as

```
glFrustumf(-10, 10, -10, 10, 1, 100)
```

but either way, whatever part is shown should be dependent on the rectangle's coordinates, right?

**UPDATE:** This is the code I'm using

```
fb1.put(new float [] {
    0,   0, -1,
    0,  10, -1,
    10, 10, -1,
    10,  0, -1
});

fb2.put(new float [] {
    0, 1,
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
    1, 1
});

indices.put(new short[] {
     0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0
});

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glFrustumf(0, 10, 0, 10, 1, 100);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, fb1);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, fb2);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.limit(),
                    GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);
}
```

The first one is what I get and the latter is what I want to get. Also I noticed that a little bit of the image is clipped vertically as well.

[image: Actual Result]
[image: Expected Result]

Comment: *drawn with left edge at -5...* What do you mean, `-5` what? Pixels? Clip Space Coordinates? How do you know what coordinate it's drawn at? And what does this mean: *And if x is translated, I'd expect y to be too.* ? I'm somewhat confused by what you're asking.

Comment: @Tim I meant object coordinates. I said that coz left half of the rectangle is outside the screen. And why isn't it vertically outside the screen.

Comment: Well I don't think that makes too much sense to me, it should be visible, if I'm understanding what you're doing correctly. One possible issue I see is that your rectangle is lying directly on the near plane, so you're one rounding error away from being clipped. Can you push it back a little bit to get away from the near plane (ex. z=2)? If you're still having problems, can you link a screenshot of your bad render, and show your full drawing code?

Comment: Your code looks correct to me based on my understanding of what you've provided, so I'm not sure why you'd be getting that result. Are you sure that your GL_MODELVIEW matrix is identity? Are you certain that your OpenGL view is centered on the screen in your android layout?

Answer (score 0):

Having the view-frustum defined with asymmetric coordinates such as `glFrustumf(0, 10, 0, 10, 1, 100)` does not mean that your positioning of objects in the world will be any different. Therefore, you should probably stick with a symmetric `glFrustumf(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1, 100)` and **move** your rectangle by modifying the `MODELVIEW` matrix.

Comment: I wanted to have the lower left point of the rectangle at the origin so that I could rotate without having to translate before and after.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no built-in OpenGL function for creating an off-center perspective matrix. You could create it yourself like this guy: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308395/how-do-you-create-an-off-center-perspectivecamera-in-wpf).

He references the math behind the matrices in his post.